# Can I upgrade a MacBook 2,1 to OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, xcode

I have a MacBook 2,1 mid-2007 model with a 2.16 GHz Intel Core2 Duo processor, 3GB of RAM and 500 GB storage with 300GB still available.

I was using this Mac to submit apps to the AppStore but for some reason I am not able to submit apps now because the minimum requirement is Xcode 5 and all I have is XCode 4.3.

In order to download Xcode 5 I need Mountain Lion 10.8 and I am currently running 10.7.4. I am not able to download 10.8 because my model is not one of the supported models.

Is there any way to install it without replacing the notebook entirely? That makes no sense to me to purchase another Mac when I have a completely healthy one. Is there some hardware upgrades I could make to make the install still proceed?

Comment: You will be unable to upgrade.

Comment: @Ramhound- I understand I am unable to upgrade by default, thats why I ask the question. Is there any hardware changes to make this upgrade possible?

Comment: @Ramhound so the only solution is to purchase a new macbook? that is so dumb on apple's part. How do I know what macbook I can purchase online that will support the upgrade if its not hardware specific?

Comment: Your laptop is 6 years old almost...

Comment: @Ramhound that means nothing. I have a PC that is almost 8 years old running windows 7 with no problem

Answer (score 0):

There are a few people on MacRumors who have claimed success installing Mountain Lion on older hardware. The problem is the video card; I believe these hacks are patching things to work with the older cards.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1325709

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1550560

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1404548